The authStateChange is not updating the authentication state, unless I restart the app debugging session, causing previous user data to be displayed
I am using authStateChange as a stream in my Splash Screen to check for any changes in the authentication state of my app, but after signing out using Firebase Auth signOut build in function, when I sign in back with a different user, it still shows the data of the previous user, fetching it from the firestore. But when I hot restart the app debugging session, it starts displaying the data of the current signed in user. I have printed the user id many times in the StreamBuilder of the authStateChange, and unless I restart the app, it prints the previous users userID. What could be the issue that forces me to restart the app to get correct data?
Here is my Splash Screen code:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:prac_crud/screens/homepage.dart';
import 'package:prac_crud/screens/login.dart';

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final User user = auth.currentUser!;
final uid = user.uid;

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({super.key});
  @override
  State<Splash> createState() {
    return _Splash();
  }
}

class _Splash extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigatetoNext();
  }

  void navigatetoNext() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print("User is: $uid");
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const HomePage();
                }
                return const Login();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Image.network(
            //   'https://images.ctfassets.net/4cd45et68cgf/7LrExJ6PAj6MSIPkDyCO86/542b1dfabbf3959908f69be546879952/Netflix-Brand-Logo.png',
            //   width: 230,
            // ),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/pngwing.com.png",
              width: 230,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            const CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I have tried printing the user ids to check the current user, still shows the previous users ID, unless restarted. Tried to reinitialize the database instance after the sign out, removed the splash and directly used StreamBuilder in the main.dart file, still no results.
The issue with the printing is solved, I just used the snapshot to print the user id, but the issue of data is still there.

The way you listen to the authStateChanges looks fine at first glance. But you're not showing any code where you actually display the value that isn't picking up the user change. Please study how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example and update your question (note: just adding more code to the question is not the solution here, construct a minimal repro from scratch).

The reason it shows previous id because the scope of that uid variable is global and final. It means it is already intialized with previous user value and will never change. So rather then using  variable if you print FirebaseAuth.Instance.currentUser.uid within stream builder, that will give current user id. You can create the Firebase auth instance global but not the user. Because it changes.
